# Package gradle is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: gradle, ubuntu-16.04

Tried to install gradle using below command.

sudo apt install gradle

But there is some problem with my machine throws the below message.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package gradle is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gradle' has no installation candidate

Comment: https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: When I run this ./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.11.12 I'm getting below error please help!
bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory